# Single handler to set values of varying types

Tags: c, data-structures, coding-style

I have a bunch of global variables which are set through callback. I get notification for one of them at a time. I want to keep single function to update this state. This is version of how I am doing.

```
typedef struct {
    int     g_var_a;
    char    g_var_b;
    double     g_var_c;
    long    g_var_d;
} global_state_t;

typedef union {
    int     g_var_a;
    char    g_var_b;
    double  g_var_c;
    long    g_var_d;
} global_change_t;

typedef enum {
    VAR_A;
    VAR_B;
    VAR_C;
    VAR_D;
} global_change_type_t;

global_state_t gs = {0};

void udpate_global_state(global_change_t *c, global_change_type_t type) {

    switch (type) {
        case VAR_A: {
            gs.g_val_a = c->g_var_a;
            break;
        }
        ...
        ....
    }
}
```

This is called as:

```
callback() {
    ...
    global_change_t c = {.g_var_a = 1234};
    update_global_state(&c, VAR_A);
}
```

But to me this looks bad. There are three construct: struct, union, enum all of which have to be in sync. Isn't there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll note that you can decrease maintenance risk by making your union with only one field per struct field *type*, not one field per field.  You can also do tricks with macros to eliminate redundancies entirely.  I can explain this further if you're interested.

You can also abstract away from the data with functions.  Unfortunately to give them all the same signature you need either a union as you used or void pointers.  I'll try the latter.

```
typedef struct {
  int     g_var_a;
  char    g_var_b;
  double  g_var_c;
  long    g_var_d;
} GLOBAL_STATE;

GLOBAL_STATE gs[1];

typedef void (*UPDATER)(void*);

void a_updater(void *val) { gs->g_var_a = *(int*)val; }
void b_updater(void *val) { gs->g_var_b = *(char*)val; }
void c_updater(void *val) { gs->g_var_c = *(double*)val; }
void d_updater(void *val) { gs->g_var_d = *(long*)val; }

void udpate_global_state(UPDATER updater, void *val) {
  updater(val);
}
```

NB You should not used types ending in `_t` as these are reserved for system headers by the C Standard.

Now you can say

```
{
  int i[1] = { 3 };
  char c[1] = { 'a' };
  double d[1] = { 1.234 };
  long g[1] = { 123456 };
  update_global_state(a_updater, i);
  update_global_state(b_updater, c);
  update_global_state(c_updater, d);
  update_global_state(d_updater, g);
}
```

The 1-element array trick is purely esthetic.  Drop it and use `&` in the update calls if you like.  Both ways produce the same code.

Of course this is not type safe, but neither is your solution.  It does reduce code structures that must be maintained in synch.

Answer (score 1):

There's no elegant way to define run-time variants in C.

The 2 approaches include:

1. `struct` containing a union with actual value and some mechanism to dispatch based on actual type. In simple case this can be an `enum` tag, in more complicated cases there will be some function pointers storing references to the `value_is()` and `get_value_as()` methods (this later approach is mostly used in dynamic language interpreters).
2. Universal value type (most often a string) which can encode distinct variant values. The receiving function will then do some simple parsing to get the data out (this is essentially equivalent to `struct` with `union` and `enum` tag), but may result in more maintainable and readable programs at an expense of some (not that big) performance loss.